# Error: Importing packages in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I downloaded a project from github https://github.com/zohebsait/ozay-backend, opened in IntelliJ IDEA IDE. This project contains some java files in it. Now I am trying to run the Application file, seems everything correct in the code but when compiling the code by right clicking Application it shows 2 errors,

> Error: "package does not exist"

but when running it it shows 100 errors.

Can anybody tell me where is the issue and fix for it?

Comment: do you download the packages which is not found? download the packages which not found and add it to your sdk path. then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it use maven to build project, you should run the "mvn clean install" command on terminal first.

Comment: Thanx for help, seems working to some extent but after running above command at last I got some errors still I thought to try to compile and run the java Application, on compilation I got no error but when I run it I got following error: [ERROR] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state, [ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

Comment: [ERROR] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use and some debug and some infos.

Comment: port is being used by another application.  You need to kill another application, try "killall java" or kill -9 pid